# google-api-python-client fails while building docker image

Tags: python, docker, google-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to build a docker image with the following command:

```
$ docker build --tag us.gcr.io/my_project_id/useradmin-global:20170907 .
```

And am getting this error:

```
Step 22/41 : RUN pip install google-api-python-client
 ---> Running in d38993b51bc0
Downloading/unpacking google-api-python-client
Downloading/unpacking oauth2client>=1.5.0,<5.0.0dev (from google-api-python-client)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.6.1,<2dev in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client)
Downloading/unpacking uritemplate>=3.0.0,<4dev (from google-api-python-client)
  Downloading uritemplate-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking httplib2>=0.9.2,<1dev (from google-api-python-client)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-g15wLp/httplib2/setup.py) egg_info for package httplib2

Downloading/unpacking pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from oauth2client>=1.5.0,<5.0.0dev->google-api-python-client)
Downloading/unpacking rsa>=3.1.4 (from oauth2client>=1.5.0,<5.0.0dev->google-api-python-client)
Downloading/unpacking pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 (from oauth2client>=1.5.0,<5.0.0dev->google-api-python-client)
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2401, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2597, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2621, in _compute_dependencies
    parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 49, in <lambda>
    next = lambda o: o.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2721, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2686, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'pyasn1 ~=0.3.4', 'at', ' ~=0.3.4')

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install google-api-python-client' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Looking at the error, it seems to be complaining that my installed version of pyasn1 is not satisfactory, expecting 0.3.4.  However, you can see it is at 0.3.4 so I'm not sure what to do here.

I tried upgrading docker to the latest version:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72
```

Which it is now.  Also tried running the pip command on it's own, which succeeds:

```
$ pip install google-api-python-client
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-python-client in /Users/mryerse001/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six<2dev,>=1.6.1 in /Users/mryerse001/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-api-python-client)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2<1dev,>=0.9.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from google-api-python-client)
Requirement already satisfied: uritemplate<4dev,>=3.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from google-api-python-client)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0 in /Users/mryerse001/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-api-python-client)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->google-api-python-client)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in /Users/mryerse001/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->google-api-python-client)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rsa-3.4.2-py2.7.egg (from oauth2client<5.0.0dev,>=1.5.0->google-api-python-client)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Docker, but with the Python module install you're trying to run *in* your Docker image.

Comment: @deceze Which is why this post is also tagged with python and google-api-client.  Do you have any helpful advice to add, or just want to comment on general technicalities that don't help in any way?

Comment: I'm pointing out that your chosen title doesn't attract the right kind of attention, and that updating Docker itself contributes nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the title to be a bit more meaningful.

Comment: have same issue yesterday, for me helps updating pip `RUN pip install -U pip` before any installition

Comment: Turns out this was a bug with one of the python libraries and has been fixed.  Running it again fixed it for me and another developer.